# Удаление докер-образов

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Как удалить все нетеггированные docker-образы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk "{print $3}")
```

Comment: Самоответ? Просто уж больно коротко. Я даже удивился.

Comment: Да. Я использую SO как пул моих заметок и исследований. Иногда это полезно другим

Comment: Должно быть наоборот: это полезно другим,  и мне иногда полезно, т.к. я использую ...

Comment: @DaemonHK  это гений самоответов :)

Comment: @zalex чем это плохо?

Comment: Не понял. Разве я сказал что это плохо ?

Comment: @zalex я воспринял как критику

Answer (score 3):

Можно выполнить очистку всех повисших образов через команду

```
docker image prune
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
```